# C++ Walkthrough cout.setf(ios::fixed); and cout.precision();

Tags: c++, walkthrough

```
/* Problem 38 */
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        class abc {
        double n;
          public:
        abc() { n = 67.5; cout << "1\n"; }
        abc(double num) { set(num); cout << "2\n"; }
        double get() const { cout<<"3\n"; return n; }
        virtual void set(double num) {
            if (num < 10)
            n = 10;
            else if (num > 100)
            n = 100;
            else
            n = num;
            cout << "4\n";
        }
        };
        class def: public abc {
        double m;
          public:
        def() { m = 6.2; cout << "5\n"; }
        def(double num1, double num2): abc(num1) {
            set(num2 - abc::get()); cout << "6\n"; }
        double get() const {
            cout << "7\n"; return m + abc::get(); }
        void set(double num) {
            if (num < 10 || 100 < num)
            m = num;
            else
            m = 55;
            cout << "8\n";
        }
        };
        void do_it(abc &var, double num)
        {   cout << var.get() << '\n';
        var.set(num);
        cout << var.get() << '\n';
        }
        int main()
        {   abc x(45);
        def y(2, 340);
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.precision(3);
        do_it(x, 200);
        do_it(y, 253);
        cout << x.get() << '\n';
        cout << y.get() << '\n';
        return 0;
        }
```

With the above code I just wanted to know what below two lines will really do in the above code

`cout.setf(ios::fixed);`
`cout.precision(3);`

Please do not just give me answer some explanation would be so appreciated because I'm doing a walkthrough to prepare for my final exam tomorrow.

I searched and some source says it is to set flags but really I don't get what is the concept of it and how it works

Comment: [`std::ios_base::setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) and [`std::ios_base::precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). Both pages have explanations of what the functions do

Comment: Thanks!

I don't really want to ruin my process of walkthrough the program but that setf [Set flag] refer to all the output or whatever is going to cout later?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *all the output or whatever is going to cout later*. You're applying formatting flags to the `std::cout` stream by calling `setf()` so it affects the way `cout` printfs stuff out in future calls.

Comment: @Prætorian Sorry that is what I meant, I was just wanted to know if it is going to apply anything that is going to `cout` later or the whole program. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed)
```

makes cout print floats with a fixed number of decimals and

```
cout.precision(3)
```

sets this number to be three.

For example, if you got a

```
double f = 2.5;
```

then

```
cout << f;
```

will print

```
2.500
```

Comment: According to the documentation `cout.unsetf(ios::fixed)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Great documentation about how to format your output : [Output formatting](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html)

It's always usefull when you're trying to do a command-line UI.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float large = 2000000000;
    cout << large;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be in scientific notation as:

```
2e+009
```

In order to get the value as it is you should use    `cout.setf(ios::fixed)`

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        float large = 2000000000;
        cout << large;
        return 0;
    }
```

The output will be as it is with default precision which is 6 for float.

```
2000000000.000000
```

You can set the precision in the above code as:

```
cout.precision(7);
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to including the manipulation library:
include :

```
<iomanip>
```

And then using the following functions

```
cout << fixed << showpoint;
cout << setprecision(3);
```